# Accessible dynamically created unordered list

Tags: reactjs, list, search, accessibility, screen-readers

I am currently tasked with making a current dynamic search accessible. Currently the search field all seems to work and announce. However when triggered the list propagates but does not seem to interact with the screen reader. I did not create this component just tasked with making it a11y compatible.

For example if I type the letter "d" in the search field the list shows all elements that match that. But on arrowDown the screen reader does not announce the value to select. I am curious if there is something I am missing here to allow that to happen, or perhaps my screen reader is just not as advanced as others.

The code is in React and as follows:

```
<div id={id} className={classNames.join(" ")} onClick={focusInput}>
  <a
    className="search-icon"
    onClick={(ev) => {
      onClickLookupIcon();
      ev.stopPropagation();
    }}
  />

  <div className={"styled-scrollbar " + itemsClassNames.join(" ")}>{itemEls}</div>

  {results.length > 0 && (
    <ul className="auto-complete" style={{ top: allowMultiple ? "42px" : "22px" }}>
      {results.map((it, i) => (
        <li
          key={i}
          className={i === selectedSearchIndex ? "selected" : ""}
          //use mousedown so that this triggers before the "blur" event on the input which would trigger selecting the `selectedSearchIndex` item instead of the clicked item
          onMouseDown={(ev) => {
            addOrReplaceItem({ type: "valid", value: it });
            resetLookup();
            ev.stopPropagation();
          }}
        >
          <SearchDelegate {...it} />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )}
</div>
```

Expanding some code to see more re {itemEls}

```
const itemEls = value.map((it) => {
    const itemId = it.type === "valid" ? getRecordId(it.value) : it.newItemId;
    return currEditingRecord === itemId ? (
      inputEl
    ) : (
      <div
        key={itemId}
        className="hg-lookup-item-wrapper"
        onClick={(ev) => {
          ev.stopPropagation();
          //edit the clicked-on item unless we're already editing it
          if (currEditingRecord === itemId) return;
          setSearchString(it.type === "valid" ? getItemSearchText(it.value) : it.searchString);
          setCurrEditingRecord(itemId);
          //select all text when clicking on existing item
          setTimeout(() => inputRef.current && inputRef.current.select());
        }}
      >
        {it.type === "valid" ? (
          <>
            <Delegate item={it.value} />
            <a className="hg-remove-icon" onClick={doRemove(itemId)} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <PendingResult<T>
            key={it.newItemId}
            loadMatches={loadMatches}
            searchString={it.searchString}
            onValueSelected={(val) => {
              onChange(
                value.map((v) =>
                  v.type === "valid" || v.newItemId !== it.newItemId || valueExists(val)
                    ? v
                    : { type: "valid", value: val },
                ),
              );
            }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  });
```

and lastly the inputEl

```
const inputEl = (
    <div key="INPUT" className="hg-lookup-item-wrapper">
      <AutosizeInput
        id={`${id}-input`}
        type="text"
        ref={inputRef}
        aria-autocomplete="list"
        aria-controls={`${id}-listbox`}
        value={searchString || ""}
        onBlur={() => {
          takeSelectedResultOrSetupPendingResult(false);
          resetLookup();
        }}
        autoComplete={"off"}
        {...{ disabled }}
        onChange={(ev) => {
          if (!allowMultiple && isAddingNewRecord() && value.length === 1) return;
          setSearchString(ev.currentTarget.value);
        }}
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I don't see you using ARIA [roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques) or [live regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions). Have you tried those?

Comment: I did and to no effect, and per the ARIA best practices page removed them.

Comment: "The ARIA best practices page"? The docs I linked indicate that this is a prime use case. What did you try?

Comment: ah yes sorry, for things already labeled as ul and li
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/listitem_role

"Only use role="list" and role="listitem" if you have to — for example if you don't have control over your HTML but are able to improve accessibility dynamically after the fact with JavaScript.

If at all possible, you should use the appropriate semantic HTML elements to mark up a list and listitems — <ol>, <ul> and <li>. 

So it should already default role to list and listitem, but I did try to do it manually as well just in case.

Comment: Yes, that would be true for static items. I think the live regions page is more relevant anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> on mouseDown the screen reader does not announce the value to select

So you're using a mouse in addition to a screen reader?  While there are some users that have that combination, the majority of screen reader users use only the keyboard and not a mouse.  Does your component work with just a keyboard?  Can you <kbd>tab</kbd> to it and the label for the component is read (WCAG 4.1.2).  If you type <kbd>d</kbd> and a list appears below it, can you arrow down to an item and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to select it (WCAG 2.1.1)?

I would initially focus on making sure everything works from a keyboard first, and then augment that work to ensure things are announced by a screen reader.  For example, typing <kbd>d</kbd> shows a list of options.  Are the number of items in the list announced?

While your object might not be a combobox, you should look at the combobox pattern, especially the "autocomplete" options.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#combobox

And check out **example 1** on:

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/combobox/aria1.1pattern/listbox-combo.html#ex1_label

Comment: ah yes sorry, it does work for tabbing. I tab to it, it announces that it is a required field and what it is. It then announces that I input (for example) the letter D then the list shows up to select but it doesn't indicate that in any way, nor does it announce anything on down arrow or anything lik ethat.

Comment: very curious, I got it to function a bit better with that. It announces what it is, for instance it announce it is an auto completion list but when it actually builds the list there is no announcement of how many items are in it, or what each item is when navigating with mouse. I assume it has to do with how this component was structured. I added more code to better give a visualization.

Comment: So I added the entirety of the code basically. It is stumping the heck out of me. I don't think it needs to be completely re-written the way it was done seems fine, just not sure why it won't seemingly announce itself as open or how many results

Comment: I’m still not getting why you mention the mouse when using the screen reader. If you arrow down the list with the keyboard when the screen reader is on, you don’t hear anything?

Comment: That is correct. So I press a letter to begin the auto complete, the list propagates and becomes visible but nothing is announced then or when arrow up or down. The mouse down was an error in my question I meant arrow down